# Why does Spliterator's getExactSizeIfKnown() NOT call hasCharacteristics()

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, spliterator

In the source (JDK 1.8.0_40) of the `Spliterator` class, the `default` implementation of `getExactSizeIfKnown()` checks to see if the instance being operated upon has the `SIZED` characteristic directly by calling the `abstract characteristics()` method and checking if it contains `SIZED`, rather than calling just calling the `hasCharacteristics(SIZED)` method, which has a `default` implementation which does pretty much the same thing.

Is there any reason why `getExactSizeIfKnown()` is not implemented as:

```
return !hasCharacteristics(SIZED) ? -1L : estimateSize();
```

which reads clearer to me and seems to handle overriding the default behaviour better (currently, if `hasCharacteristics(int)` is overriden to something bizzare, there is *no* indication that `getExactSizeIfKnown()` should probably also be overriden)?

Is there something I'm missing here?  Why duplicate the check between methods like this?

Comment: Well, I found [this discussion](http://core-libs-dev.openjdk.java.narkive.com/ePYu20y1/rfr-jdk-8011426-java-util-collection-spliterator-implementations) where Paul Sandoz said "We could, it is marginally more efficient not to."

Comment: I don't see a strong reason why it *should* be implemented in the way you propose. All arguments in either direction seem fairly weak. So my guess would be the implementors simply chose the one they personally liked.

Comment: @Tunaki Nice digging!

Comment: @the8472 - "currently, if hasCharacteristics(int) is overriden to something bizzare, there is no indication that getExactSizeIfKnown() should probably also be overriden" - don't you feel that's a strong reason?  It's pretty much Item 17 right out of Effective Java.

Comment: To me that's only an argument for changing documentation to explicitly spell out things, not for changing the implementation. Also, you're looking at a default default method vs. an abstract one. Consider which one must and will be implemented and which one won't. `hasCharacteristics` is only overridden once in the whole JDK, and all it does is delegate to a wrapped Spliterator. So I stand by my claim, no strong reasons why it should be implemented differently.

Comment: @Tom Tresansky: if you override `hasCharacteristics(int)` “to something bizarre” whose result contradicts the result of the `characteristics()` implementation of the same class, you are the only one to blame for whatever will happen then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question apparently came up during the design of the `Spliterator` class. Quoting Paul Sandoz in [this discussion](http://core-libs-dev.openjdk.java.narkive.com/ePYu20y1/rfr-jdk-8011426-java-util-collection-spliterator-implementations) on the OpenJDK mailing list:

> > *Post by Mike Duigou*
> >     - `getExactSizeIfKnown()` - use `hasCharacteristics`?
>
> We could, it is marginally more efficient not to.

So it seems there was no strong reason, only a minor performance consideration.

On another note, I don't think your argument about overriding `hasCharacteristics(int)` to "something bizarre" really holds. If you were to override `hasCharacteristics(int)`, the implementation of `characteristics()` would also need to be consistent with that "bizarre" behaviour, else you would be breaking the contract of the Spliterator. Note that the implementation specification (which describes required behaviour of conforming implementations) of [`getExactSizeIfKnown()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Spliterator.html#getExactSizeIfKnown--) says:

> The default implementation returns the result of `estimateSize()` if the `Spliterator` reports a characteristic of `SIZED`, and -1 otherwise.

Based on that, if you override the behaviour of the Spliterator characteristics, you have been warned that `getExactSizeIfKnown()` will be, by default, impacted.

Comment: A good point about the class' requirement to keep `characteristics()` and `hasCharacteristics(int)` in sync, which sidesteps the problem.